# Taking formatted pdf and converting to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I have a pdf that puts contact info per page and rest of the page is blank. I want to convert this pdf to excel but have it organized in columns and rows so I can print out as a list. How can I do that?

Comment: That is a fairly difficult product and you may need a paid tool to do it.  Here is a decent tutorial to get you started: https://www.investintech.com/resources/blog/archives/7898-convert-pdf-excel-formatting-issues.html

Comment: Power BI has a connector that can read PDF data and chances are that this connector will be available for Excel Power Query soon.

Comment: So power bi can breakdown the pdf and scraping the formatting into what I want. It's the same format for each page so if i can just tell it to take format 1 pdf to format 1 a excel it can do that for all my pages?

Comment: @Vick,, could you share the file or portion so we could test it to suggest the method!

Comment: How do I upload a file?

Comment: how did it become a pdf? Can you request a different file format, like excel...

Comment: Not sure how it becomes pdf. They won't give excel format. I going to play around it some more. I think I can copy and paste the data but it wont be in table form. Is there a way I scan make s text program that would  take the info and organize it as columns and rows?

Comment: You can try excel's built-in data manipulation tools (aka. Get & Transform Data).

Answer (score 0):

You can try tabula. It extracts tables from PDFs quite well.
https://tabula.technology/
And it's free!